# Want to create a custom component that mirror existing component functionalities, but using different renderer

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component, selectonemenu

The JSF component `SelectOneRadio` layout is very limited so I wrote a custom Renderer for it, and it works great. However, there are times when I want to use the standard SelectOneRadio layout as well. So I decide to make my new component that utilize the custom Renderer I create, but I want this new component to mirror the functionality of `SelectOneRadio`, and the only different is that it will use my Renderer. Do I need to create both `custom tag` and `custom component` to go with my `custom renderer` in this case? What `class` should I extends to obtain all functionalities from `SelectOneRadio`? I would greatly appreciated if you can provided some codes.

**EDIT**
@BalusC: I like your idea about detecting the value of `layout` to delegate the correct renderer. So if I have layout="div_layout", then it works great, but if it is `pageDirection` or `lineDirection` and nothing show up. What I did is: I create a class that `extends MenuRenderer` and I override `encodeEnd` method, so in there I did this

```
String layout = (String) component.getAttributes().get("layout");

if(layout != null){
        if(layout.equals(PAGE_DIRECTION) || layout.equals(LINE_DIRECTION)){
            super.encodeEnd(context, component);
            return;
        } else if (!layout.equals(DIV_LAYOUT)){
            //Throw error message
        }
}
//Continue with my own renderer code
```

**EDIT2**
Above when I said nothing show up, I was wrong. super.encodeEnd(context, component); did render, but instead of render the radio, it render `select option` tag. So it seems that I delegate to the wrong renderer. I need to use RadioRenderer instead of MenuRenderer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's specific to your own web application, then you could replace just alone the renderer. Easiest is to extend the implementation specific renderer and then depending on the value of one of the standard attributes (`layout` is the best choice) either delegate to the implementation specific renderer, or do your own custom rendering job.

I case of Mojarra, you'd like to extend [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.1.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/RadioRenderer.java) and then register it as follows

```
<renderkit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Radio</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.ExtendedRadioRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</renderkit>
```

If you wish to be implementation independent, then you'd need to write the entire renderer implementation yourself.

If you wish to have a custom component for it, then you'd need to write it yourself as well.

Comment: I think I over engineer this. Your idea about detecting the `layout` attribute and delegate to the correct renderer seems better. I have it almost working correctly, please refer back to my original post as I have just one more question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Above when I said nothing show up, I was wrong. `super.encodeEnd(context, component);` did render, but instead of render the `radio`, it render `select option` tag. So it seems that I delegate to the wrong renderer. Do you know by any chance know the correct renderer?

Comment: As stated in my answer, you should extend `RadioRenderer`, not `MenuRenderer`. The `MenuRenderer` is for `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Sorry, I did saw that last night. I was able to get it working last night. However, the code is still intrusive. I am still looking for way to make it less intrusive.

Comment: To be implementation independent, you mean? Then don't extend the implementation-specific renderer, but then write the whole bunch of code yourself. For the component part you could extend the standard JSF `HtmlSelectOneRadio`.